# With pg and pg-format, how can I update arbitrary fields of a row, or update only certain fields of a row where the fields may be different each time

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I'm interacting with a postgres database using pg (node-postgres) and pg-format to sanitize and prevent SQL injection.

Let's say I have a table called game_options. Rows in this table include three fields: option_1, option_2 and option_3. When I update a row I want to avoid unnecessary writes and only update the fields passed to my update function. Sometimes I may want to update only option_3, other times I might want to update option_1 and option_3. How can I write a function to accomplish this?

I currently have this:

```
 static async update(userId: number, updatedOptions: PartialValues) {
    // extract the keys and values into an array so I can spread them as arguments for pg-format
    const keysAndValues: any[] = [];
    Object.entries(updatedOptions).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      keysAndValues.push(key);
      keysAndValues.push(value);
    });

    const queryText = format(
      `UPDATE game_options SET ${Object.keys(updatedOptions)
        .map(() => "%I = %L")
        .join(", ")} WHERE user_id = %L`,
      ...keysAndValues,
      userId
    );

    const { rows } = await wrappedPool.query(format(queryText));
    return toCamelCase(rows)![0] as unknown as IBattleRoomConfigSettings;
```

But it does not format correctly and adds extra double quotes to every field name except the first one in the list, and also outputs numbers as strings.

Been googling, chat-gpt and tinkering for the last hour or so with no luck. This seems like such a simple thing to do but I can't find a good example anywhere.

Comment: There is no point in trying to *avoid unnecessary writes* as Postgres **always** writes every column. An update is essentially a delete and insert.